# How to write all date between 2 dates? +1

Tags: php, date

I have 2 existing dates and I want to print those dates. But I set these 2 dates 1 day is missing.

How do I add 1 day?

The date range used in the code: 2019-10-07 - 2019-11-06

**Missing Date:**
2019-11-06 How can I add?

**MY CODE:**

```
<?php
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime("2019-10-07"),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime("2019-11-06")
);

foreach ($period as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->format('Y-m-d');
    echo '<br />';
}

// RESULT::
// 2019-10-07
// 2019-10-08
// 2019-10-09
// 2019-10-10
// 2019-10-11
// 2019-10-12
// 2019-10-13
// 2019-10-14
// 2019-10-15
// 2019-10-16
// 2019-10-17
// 2019-10-18
// 2019-10-19
// 2019-10-20
// 2019-10-21
// 2019-10-22
// 2019-10-23
// 2019-10-24
// 2019-10-25
// 2019-10-26
// 2019-10-27
// 2019-10-28
// 2019-10-29
// 2019-10-30
// 2019-10-31
// 2019-11-01
// 2019-11-02
// 2019-11-03
// 2019-11-04
// 2019-11-05
?>
```

Comment: set the end period to +1 day ?

Comment: @Dale I didn't try that. But I want to edit the existing code. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you change `new DateTime("2019-11-06")` to `new DateTime("2019-11-05")`?

Comment: Assuming you can't change the hardcoded value:
`$end = new DateTime("2019-11-06");
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');` Then replace the last valeu in your `DatePeriod ` with `$end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my function

```
public function getDatesFromPeriodPerDay($startDate, $endDate){
    $begin = new \DateTime( $startDate );
    $end   = new \DateTime( $endDate );
    $end   = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
    $interval  = new \DateInterval('P1D');
    $dateRange = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
    $dates = array();
    foreach($dateRange as $date) {
        $dates [] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bump the day up by one like this:

```
<?php

$last  = new DateTime("2019-11-06"); // i take it this comes from elsewhere?
$last->modify('+1 day'); // so just do this to it

$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime("2019-10-07"),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    $last
);

foreach ($period as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->format('Y-m-d');
    echo "\n";
}
```